# Dealing with throttled Mouse Move events in .NET

Tags: c#, .net, mouse, point, mousemove

I am trying to write a form which the user can draw on by holding down and moving the mouse.  Therefore I am subscribing to the MouseMove event and using the Point given to draw a Pixel at that point.

Unfortunately, the faster I move the mouse, the more points are skipped and discarded by the message queue, so instead of me ending up with a line drawn by a pen, I end up with a series of points.

Do I need to manually fill in the blanks between each point?  And if so, what is a good algorithm to calculate a list of the points between two points.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could just save the points as line segments while the user draws and display those using Graphics.DrawLine. If you *do* want the actual points, you'll have to decide on whether you want straight lines or interpolate arcs (rounded) through them.

For straight lines there's [http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bresenham's_line_algorithm](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bresenham%27s_line_algorithm) - arcs are a little bit more complicated :)

Answer (score 0):

You should simply draw a line from the last point you saw the mouse at to the current location.

Answer (score 0):

The normal procedure for drawing in this way is to use lines, not points. The pseudocode is as follows:

```
on mousemove
{
    draw line from lastCoord to current coordinate
    store current coordinate in lastCoord
}

on mousedown
{
    store current coordinate in lastCoord
}
```

Answer (score 0):

you should just use two points: the point when the user presses the mouse button ([`MouseDown`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.control.mousedown%28v=VS.100%29.aspx)) and the point when he releases the mousebutton ([`MouseUp`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.control.mouseup.aspx))... then you draw a line between these two points.

For example with [`Graphics.DrawLine`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/f956fzw1.aspx) method...